# Weird response when I ping x.x.x.255

Tags: networking, ip, ping, redirection, subnet

This is my computer network configuration:

```
C:\Users\user>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f56e:2272:8e45:d325%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.81
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.60
```

The question is *Why when I `ping` the IP address `10.0.0.255`, I see the following result:*

```
C:\Users\User>ping 10.0.0.255

Pinging 10.0.0.255 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.255:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\User>ping 10.0.0.255

Pinging 10.0.0.255 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.255:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

As you see above, instead of returning nothing (because `10.0.0.255` is not a valid IP address and it is my network bradcast IP) it pings `10.0.0.5` and `10.0.0.154`! Why?

Note that I checked `hosts` file under `Windows\system32\drivers\etc\` path and as you see there is no redirection there:

[image]

**Update:**

```
C:\Users\user>ping -t 10.255

Pinging 10.0.0.255 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.5: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.154: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.255:
    Packets: Sent = 49, Received = 49, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
Control-C
^C
C:\Users\user>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because Ping is a broadcast-compatible service. A computer that receives such an echo request will happily reply.

Comment: Does that mean my ping request is sent to all the network clients and I receive the first answer?

Comment: No. As you can see from the first output, it shows *all* answers.

Comment: But there is one hundred clients in my network with IP = `10.0.0.X`. Why I only receive only this two answers?! Why I didn't received any answer from `10.0.0.5` in the second time?

Comment: Well then I guess it’s the first answer you receive for each echo request sent. Still, all machines answer, you can inspect it with a packet sniffer like Wireshark

Comment: Question updated. All the times `10.0.0.154` win the race condition?!

Comment: `10.0.0.154` is an HSM connected to a Switch with IP `10.0.0.5`. I unplugged the HSM from the switch. Now I receive response from `10.0.0.5` only while there are a lot of devices connected to this switch in the same IP range. Why in the first case (HSM connected) the switch broadcast my `ping` request and return me the first answer, but in the second case (HSM disconnected) it respond me itself and doesn't broadcast my `ping` request?

Comment: It’s entirely possible for the same device to always respond first. It depends on the physical path, after all. A switch is usually optimized for distributing traffic, not for responding to echo requests or whatnot.

Comment: _A switch is usually optimized for distributing traffic, not for responding to echo requests or whatnot_ But when I disconnect the HSM from the switch, the switch itself respond me the echo requests. why? Specially when there are some other devices connected to this switch!

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question if you’re that interested in this specific issue. It wasn’t part of your original question. It’s virtually impossible to answer unless you know everything about all devices involved. It could depend on the tiniest implementation detail.